# Is my idea of using GIT with localhost right?

Tags: git

First of all, I apologize for stupid question, I've always been using GIT, but as standalone programmer for my own projects, because it was making things easier when working from several computers.
I didn't have to copy zipped files, I just used Git command lines to fetch new version anytime I changed my computer.

Now I'm using it for a first time as part of a team.

It is NodeJS + Mongo project

Now, if I clone a repository to my local computer and I want it to work with my local database I oboviusly need to change some settings to make it work on local machine.
Things like DB url, username, password and also API URL's etc .

But later when I commit, I don't want my settings to 'overwrite' settings of other users, they work on their local machines too.

So what I should do is work normally on my localhost, prepare changes in local enviroment, but before commiting I should only add those files which are same for all team members, excluding settings file,  am I thinking right ?

What are other good practices ?

Comment: The good practices is to exclude configuration from the repository at all and/or use environment variables.

Comment: @zerkms Yes, that makes sense. And what if that is not possible for some reason? Then commiting only part of files good idea ?

Comment: You don't have other choice I think.

Comment: @zerkms Thank you very much for you answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, if you are on a team, you fork the repository you are working on.

All changes done on your fork you commit to your repo, commit as much as you want as that is your repo. Work on your local host here and add features and settings, verify they work.

When you are ready pull any changes done to the master repo and then merge to yours, usually at this point in time if your settings are different aka you forget to change the local host settings back to regular, git will flag it and ask you to resolve the conflict comparing it to master. Resolve the conflict then merge them. Repeat for Master so they are identical.

Generally if you are in a group you all should not be carelessly working live with the master branch as it should hold the most stable version of whatever you are working on.

Take note as long as there is a commit, there is an undo so even if something screws up, hit it and revert to a previous commit.

Comment: By "fork", do you mean forking in the GitHub sense or just cloning the remote repository to have your local copy? I would advice not to call the latter fork, it's just cloning a repository to obtain a local copy, in which you can work as you described.

Answer (score 0):

User setting should not be part of the repository in the first place. The usual practice is to ignore files containing user settings in the repositorys' [gitignore file](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore). This way, git just ignores them and they are not shown as added or changed files in any git context, so you can just work on your project and don't have to worry about any user or machine related settings.